# Using Yield statement to return output when search query is not found using scrapy python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I was following a tutorial to scrape multiple pages from a website using scrapy library. The tutorial used yield statement to get information from the html and css structure of the page using css selectors and xpath selectors.  I decide to use an if statement to check whether a search query finds a result and an else statement to output what to do when a search query did not encounter a result. The problem arises when the code executes the else statement which extracts the company's name and for the Location and Sales field I want a customized output string that conveys 'Not Found'.

When I run the script I get the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\....\hoover-scraper\scraper.py", line 28

'Location': 'Not Found'
         ^
```

I think this is not a proper way to use the yield statement that's why I am getting the SyntaxError message. Thus I was wondering if there was any way to output the strings 'Not found' for sales and location fields for when a query encounters an empty search.

This part of my code:

```
def parse(self, response):
    NAME_SELECTOR ="td a::text"
    LOCATION_SELECTOR ='.//tr/td/text()' #using xpath to grab information for Location and Sales
    SALES_SELECTOR = './/tr/td/text()' 

if response.css(NAME_SELECTOR).extract_first(): #Checks to see if the company name field has data if not prints 'No results found'
        yield {

            'Company Name': response.css(NAME_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
            'Location' : response.xpath(LOCATION_SELECTOR)[0].extract(), #Location comes first inside the td tags thus the [0]
            'Sales' : response.xpath(SALES_SELECTOR)[1].extract(),
        }

    else:
        yield {
            'Company Name': response.css("dd.value.term::text").extract_first() #identifies company name which data was not found
            'Location': 'Not Found'
            'Sales': 'Not Found'
        }
```

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yield` is used only in generators. Do you just want to return that value from your method? Then replace `yield` with `return` in both places.

If you need to use the value later in the same method, assign the dictionary to a variable. Like

```
if response.css(NAME_SELECTOR).extract_first(): #Checks to see if the company name field has data if not prints 'No results found'
        result = {

            'Company Name': response.css(NAME_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
            'Location' : response.xpath(LOCATION_SELECTOR)[0].extract(), #Location comes first inside the td tags thus the [0]
            'Sales' : response.xpath(SALES_SELECTOR)[1].extract(),
        }

    else:
        result = {
            'Company Name': response.css("dd.value.term::text").extract_first(), #identifies company name which data was not found
            'Location': 'Not Found',
            'Sales': 'Not Found'
        }
    # do something with result
    ...
    # or just:
    return result
```

Comment: Yes I need to use these values later, so converting them to a dictionary works for me. I just added coma after each dictionary entry in the else statement and it worked.